# PostgreSQL: select distinct id union vs. select id full join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to retrieve a full list of `id` from multiple tables and they could be completely overlapped or mutually exclusive. I am wondering which will have better performance and which is the right way for PostgreSQL, and why is that so?

Say I have 4 tables, and tables are optimized with indices:

**[SELECT DISTINCT ... UNION]**

```
SELECT DISTINCT id from table1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT id from table2
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT id from table3
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT id from table4
;
```

**[SELECT ... FULL JOIN]**

```
SELECT DISTINCT coalesce(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id) AS id
FROM table1 a
FULL JOIN table2 b on a.id=b.id
FULL JOIN table3 c on b.id=c.id
FULL JOIN table4 d on c.id=d.id
;
```

*Made some adjustments here. Thanks to @Hogan's suggestion in his answer.*

**Notes**

My entire motivation for the `full join` is because `id` field could be completely overlapped among tables. `full join` could alleviate some of the table scans.

Comment: these are not the same

Comment: There is no need for distinct with `UNION`. `UNION` returns distinct values. `UNION ALL` returns all values

Comment: @lad2025 . . . There is no need, but there are cases where it can produce a better execution plan (namely, when an index can be used for the `distinct` in the subquery).  That said, the two queries are not equivalent, so I doubt that the OP is aware of that nuance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is approximately ~2M records in each table, and the `id` field is a 20-character string. There could be up to 20~30% duplicated id in each table. I have also set up an index on `id` for each table. I guess the `distinct` in each table will make a difference here? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There are so many factors here, but what are you doing with the list of IDs -- just putting it on the screen?

Comment: @Hogan, I am left joining those ids to the main table and counting how many overlaps are there. For example, I have a user main table with user id, and I have 4 other tables describing different types of user behavior. I would like to know how many users had activities and how many had no activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are not equivalent.  The first does what you want; the second doesn't.  From that perspective, the "performance" award goes to the first:  correct results beat faster queries.

This fixes the second version:

```
SELECT id
from table1 a FULL JOIN
     table2 b
     using (id) FULL JOIN
     table3 c
     using (id) FULL JOIN
     table4
     using (id);
```

(You only need `distinct` if one of the tables could have multiple ids.)

As with any performance question, you should try with your data on your system.

Comment: this does not look right, how does it know what table `id`  is from in the select cause (might be a feature of postgresql I don't know)?

Comment: the using part in each join tells the database that these columns are the same. i vagely remember it as part of the standard but never saw it except with postgresql

Comment: @Aツ -- I always saw using as a short cut for a join not as "the same" since the values won't be the same with with a full join -- some will be null.

Comment: @Hogan . . . I think you get an error if you try to specify  a table alias for `id` in the `select`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff then which table.id will it use?

Comment: @Hogan . . . It returns a value, not `NULL`.  It is equivalent to `coalesce(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id)`.

Comment: The behaviour that the join column is only returned once when `using()` is used for the join condition, _is_ defined in the standard and not specific to Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40bfc9/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86756/1

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment above I would recommend the following -- I think this would be the most likely to give good performance as a result of giving the server the most opportunity to optimize the process.  I have not done any tests and don't have anything to back this up expect experience and intuition:

1. Create a temporary table with a single column of the ID type.  Add an index to this column.
2. For the first table select all the id and insert into this table.
3. For each of following tables select all the IDs except (eg not in) the temporary table and insert into the temp table.
4. Perform your actual query using the temporary table.

---

your second query is not the same.  I believe this is what you meant

```
SELECT DISTINCT coalesce(a.id,b.id,c.id,d.id) as id
from table1 a
FULL JOIN table2 b on a.id=b.id
FULL JOIN table3 c on b.id=c.id
FULL JOIN table4 d on c.id=d.id
```

this way def. looks uglier, I would need to be test to see if it is slower, I'd expect a good optimizer to have the same performance on both.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. This is what I meant. I will edit the question.